# BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

I ran npm update and it gave me bootstrap v4.1.2.

**On start gives the Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query 'dead' error.**

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you are using older version of angular 
you have to *delete* **browserslist** file from **src** folder

Comment: Thanks!! deleting the browserslist file from the root folder of my mac did solve the issue.

Comment: You saved my day, bro. +1

Answer (score 9):

For those that might experience this error on a React App.

Make a new file called .browserlistrc and cut the browserlist part away from package.json paste into the newly created file.

.browserlistrc

```
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cotd",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "5.6.0",
    "node": "9.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.5.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.27",
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "0.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "stylus": "0.54.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Run build again

Answer (score 3):

By deleting the "browserslist" section in package.json, the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Changing my 
*package.json*
 from `"bootstrap": "^4.1.2"` to `"bootstrap": "4.1.1"` AND running

`npm install bootstrap`

solved my problem.

> **Notice** that I removed `^` sign aswell

I guess its a problem in Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same issue on `bootstrap` version `4.1.2`. It seems that the version `4.1.3` fixed it. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this same issue embedding tailwind to an existing react project, i fixed mine by simply removing autoprefixer value and setting it to an empty string ("").

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: "./tailwind.js",
    autoprefixer: ""
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, a possible solution is to remove the `~` from `development` inside `browserslist` inside `package.json`.

so just change:

```
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version~",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
```

to

```
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Laravel mix

```
npm remove laravel-mix
```

and then update

```
npm install laravel-mix@^4.0.0 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

just install react on root directory /home/{username}/hereeeeeeee