# Error in Unknown browser query `dead` in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, render

I am developing a login function inside App class. However, When I put the Style.css file into App.js return me the following message: `Error in Unknown browser query` dead`"`. I wanna know what this is about and how can I solve it.

This is my app.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import './styles.css';
import {AiOutlineLock} from 'react-icons/ai';
import {AiOutlineMail} from 'react-icons/ai';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <body>
      <form class="login">
        <img src={''} alt="" />
        <div class = "inputs">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="email" placeholder="userexample@mail.com" />
          </div>
          <div class="password-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <input type="password" placeholder="....." />
            </div>
            <a href="/reset_password">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/dashboard">
          <button>ingresar</button>
        </a>
      </form>
    </body>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here's my `Style.css`:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}


.form{
  background-color: white;
}

input {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #41c0f3;
}

a {
  text-align: end;
  color: #41c0f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(65, 192, 243, 1) 0%,
    rgba(19, 181, 117, 1) 100%
  );
}

svg {
  color: #41c0f3;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.inputs {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #41c0f3;
}

.password-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I'd be grateful if someone could provide some help.

Thanks and nice day for all!

Comment: What exactly is returning that message? The build-step? The browser-log?

Comment: Hello! "Error in Unknown browser query `dead`" - Is the error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501138/browserslisterror-unknown-browser-query-dead